# Determine if it $\forall a>0$ there exists a solution to $ax+(a+1)y=7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've tried finding a counterexample, but these kinds of questions usually are true. When I tried proving it I thought that the GCD $(a,a+1)=1$, which means that $(a,a+1)\mid 7$, $\forall a>0$, which then means that such a Diophantine equation has a solution. Is this valid?

Comment: Your argument is correct.

Answer (score 1):

We can use general theory, as you did, or we can be explicit: Let $x=7a$ and $y=7(1-a)$.

Answer (score 0):

For every integer $a$, we have $(a + 1) -a = 1$, and so $(a+1)n + a (-n) = n$, for every other integer $n$. In particular, $(a+1)7 + a (-7) = 7$. So you can take $x=7$ and $y=-7$.